# Android game development - Java or flash development or flash animation?

Tags: android

I'm trying to make an android game here, but I'm not sure what is it that I need to learn - J2ME or flash development? 
Also, if flash then is there a difference between flash development (coding) & flash animation? 
I'd really appreciate any help  here.

Comment: You don't want flash on android. and android does not have JavaME, it was a VM called devik. So you should use Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a good [read](http://www.rbgrn.net/content/54-getting-started-android-game-development) for you

Answer (score 0):

Java would be the way to go. Due to the fact that java has greater flexibility and is easier to start off with in certain aspects.
Flash/Flex/ActionScript can be easier with designing graphics but the scripting can get a bit complex and tedious.
http://androidforums.com/android-games/217545-should-i-use-flash-air-java-develop-games.html

Google yields many results.
[Android game development tutorials](http://www.google.co.za/#hl=en&sa=X&ei=aGxOT6yLBJK0hAfBl9kD&sqi=2&ved=0CDQQvwUoAQ&q=Android+game+development+tutorials&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=47b318a0a1125e11&biw=1463&bih=736)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to go the easy route, I'd recommend Flash/Flex/ActionScript.  Flash/Flex/ActionScript programming can all be comingled to a certain extent.  Flash animations are typically done in a more graphical environment but you can absolutely create your objects programmatically and make them do the same things through Flex/ActionScript.

Also, you may want to look into the controversy over HTML5 and Javascript.  That might be a viable alternative for you.  Plus, it would double as getting familiar with desigining sites as well.

Answer (score 0):

Java is the only way to go. Adobe has abandoned mobile Flash, and even before that, only a limited subset of Android devices supported flash.

The only sensible option is Java with the Android SDK.